# Plotting multiple lists together with their avarages in a single plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, time-series, smoothing

I have as example multiple lists of x data (in mm) http://pastebin.com/7xwgGDsd which I want to plot against time (in sec).

```
time = Table[t/60, {t, 1, number}] // N;
x = Get@"http://pastebin.com/raw/7xwgGDsd";

ListPlot[Transpose[{time, #}] & /@ Transpose[x], PlotRange -> Full, 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"x (m)", ""}, {"t (sec)", ""}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

As next I calculate the moving average of each list:

```
xaverage = MovingAverage[#, 180] & /@ Transpose[x];
naverage = 
  Length@xaverage[[1, All]]; (*is same for each averaged list*)

ListPlot[Transpose[{time[[1 ;; naverage]], #}] & /@ xaverage, 
 PlotRange -> Full, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"x (m)", ""}, {"t (sec)", ""}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Finally **I would like to put everything in one plot** by using `ListPlot` to plot the x lists and if appropriate `Epilog` to plot the moving average lists.

To do that I tried the following, but it fails:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{time, #}] & /@ Transpose[x], 
 Epilog -> {Thickness[0.002], Line[#] & /@ xavarage}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"x (m)", ""}, {"t (sec)", ""}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

How can I solve this problem?
(For my real data is `Dimensions[x] = {2726, 10}` -> 10 x data lists)

Comment: Why not use `Show`?

Comment: @xslittlegrass: can you show an example on how you would solve this with a variable number of lists (not only 2 data sets with average curves, but more)? The nice thing of `ListPlot` that it chooses different colors for each pair of raw and average data.

Comment: Why not go for [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html?q=TemporalData)? If you take a look at *Applications* there, you will see how `Show`is used for multiple paths.

Comment: @gwr: This is interesting, I have to read the documentation and will try it out.

Comment: The variable `number`is never defined here. Maybe you should change the question to make its value clear (e.g. as in my answer `Length @ x`?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a quick answer based upon [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) and the use of [`MovingMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html):

```
x = Get@"http://pastebin.com/raw/7xwgGDsd";
time = Table[t/60, { t, 1, Length @ x }] // N; (* seconds *)

(* make these data TemporalData *)
td = TemporalData[Transpose[{time, #}] & /@ Transpose[x]];

$PlotTheme = "Scientific";
Show[ {
    ListLinePlot @ td, 
    ListLinePlot[ 
        MovingMap[ Mean, td, Quantity[180, "Events"] ], 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Orange] 
    ]
  }, 
  ImageSize -> Large,
  FrameLabel -> {{"x (m)", ""}, {"t (sec)", ""}}
]
```

> [image: MovingAveragesRight]

### Update

To shift the MovingAverage this specification of the *window* alignment for `MovingMap`can be used:

```
Show[{
    ListLinePlot @ td, 
    ListLinePlot[ 
        MovingMap[ Mean, td, { Quantity[180, "Events"], Left } ],
        PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Orange]
    ]
  }, 
  ImageSize -> Large,
  FrameLabel -> {{"x (m)", ""}, {"t (sec)", ""}}
]
```

[image: MovingAveragesLeft]

### Update 2: Solution without `Show`

Since a lot of people seem to mistrust `Show` I would like to point out that there is no need for it:

```
augmentedTD = TemporalData[
    {
      td, (* the original time series *)
      MovingMap[ Mean, td, { Quantity[180, "Events"], Center } ] (* MovingAverages, centered *)
    }
]; 

ListLinePlot[
    augmentedTD, (* or augmentedTD["Paths"], augmentedTD["Path", 1], ... *)
    PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "CoolColors", "LargeLabels" },
    ImageSize -> Large,
    FrameLabel -> {{"x (m)", None }, {"t (sec)", None }}]
]
```

[image: MovingAveragesCentered]

Note that, as pointed out in the comments, one can easily access each single time series by using `augmentedTD["Path", i]` where `i ∈ [1,4]`.

Comment: Great, only one thing, can the average curves be shifted to left? Would this solution also work for many data sets (with only two lines in `Show`)?

Comment: Please note, that the `MovingAverage`must have a *gap* since it uses 180 data points to come up with a value. Using `TemporalData`and `MovingMap`will be true to the *times* -- no streching of curves as in simply using `ListPlot` and `Lists`. My advice: If you have `TimeSeries` go for TimeSeries-Functionality - it is eventually *safer* to do so.

Comment: @mrz I have now updated my solution to demonstrate that `Show` is not needed which further demonstrates the power of the `TemporalData` framework.

Comment: How did you find all the possible `units` of `Quantity`, like `"Events"`. What is t-step in which the t-window is moved?

Answer (score 4):

*I've updated this answer in response to gwr's comments.  The original answer can be found in the edit history.*

I prefer to avoid using Show to combine multiple `ListPlot`s when possible.  @gwr makes a good point that one should leverage the time-based functions of *Mathematica* in cases where the data are temporal; however, it is still possible to achieve the desired output without using `TemporalData`

```
x = Get@"http://pastebin.com/raw/7xwgGDsd";
time = Table[t/60, {t, 1, Length@x}] // N;(*seconds*)
With[{data = Partition[Riffle[time, #], 2] & /@ Transpose[x]},
 ListPlot[Join[data, MovingAverage[#, 180] & /@ data], 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"x (m)", ""}, {"t (sec)", ""}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
]
```

[image]

Because a moving average will not be defined for the first and last n/2 points, your results should have "missing" data at both the beginning and end of the plot.

Note, in this answer, I am taking advantage of the uniform distribution of points in your dataset, so the (moving)average time at a particular point is equal to that time.  I have not thought through whether or not this applies to a non-uniform distribution of points.

Interestingly, there is a subtle difference between the use of `MovingMap[Mean,data,n]` and  `MovingAverage[data,n]` when applied to a list of {x,y} pairs.  I'm not quite sure what the difference is, so be careful when interchanging them.

Comment: I like your solution ... it is may be not so "readable" as using `TemporalData` but it is the fastest ...

Comment: @mrz But we should note that the solution given with ListPlot alone is maybe not the *truest* solution:  Note that `MovingAverage` produces 2547 data points while the original data have 2726 points. So there *must* be data missing for the moving averages (if placed left, then to the right). But there is **no gap**! If you remove `DataRange` here you will see the same result as given in the `TemporalData`solution - very tricky. What I like about `TemporalData`is that it is completely true to your *time* information.

Comment: @gwr I agree.  A correct answer would pass {x,y} pairs to `ListPlot`.  I wanted to demonstrate that raw and processed data can all be passed as arguments without the need for epilog; and further, the processing can be done within ListPlot without having to assign a new symbol to the processed data.  Doing it correctly would become less readable, however.

Comment: I agree with that, but essentially - as of now - this is a readable, fast and *wrong* solution. Maybe one should assign some value to truth in scientific computing? :)

Comment: @gwr point well taken, and I have updated my answer in response to your comments.  Can you comment on why your answer gives a value for the moving average at the end of the dataset?  Should there be gaps at both the beginning and end?

Comment: @bobthechemist One can probably lead a heated debate about what is the *right way* of doing it. If one understands the moving average as an estimate for the actual or next state (filtering) I would put the window to the left (gap to the right). I simply followed mrz's wish to have it at the left. Note that you can also use the option `Center` for `MovingMap` alignment.

Comment: Well, one would need to tell left from right, right? :) So Right for filtering makes sense; Left and Center for smoothing imo.

Comment: @gwr that makes sense; I only use moving average for smoothing, which undoubtedly is biasing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For version 9, there is `` TemporalData`EnsembleMovingMap ``:

```
x = Get@"http://pastebin.com/raw/7xwgGDsd";
time = Table[t/60, {t, 1, Length@x}] // N;
td = TemporalData[Transpose[{time, #}] & /@ Transpose[x]];

ListPlot[TemporalData[{td, TemporalData`EnsembleMovingMap[Mean, td, 180]}],
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If needed, wrap the moving map with `` TemporalData`ShiftTimes ``:

```
ListPlot[TemporalData[{td, 
   TemporalData`ShiftTimes[TemporalData`EnsembleMovingMap[Mean, td, 180], -3]}],
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint from xslittlegrass one can do also the following:

```
time = Table[t/60, {t, 1, number}] // N;
x << "http://pastebin.com/raw/7xwgGDsd";

nPoints = 180; (* Moving Average over 180 points*)
xaverage = MovingAverage[#, nPoints] & /@ Transpose[x];
naverage = 
 Length@xaverage[[1, All]]; (*is same for each averaged list*)

Show[
 ListLinePlot[Transpose[{time, #}] & /@ Transpose[x]], 
 ListLinePlot[
  Transpose[{time[[nPoints/2 ;; Length@time - nPoints/2]], #}] & /@ xaverage], 
 PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"x (m)", ""}, {"t (sec)", ""}}, ImageSize -> Large
]
```

[image]